# Read list of numbers by place value? (ClojureScript tricks)

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I was wondering today if i have a list of numbers. Is there a function in ClojureScript which returns a number made from the numbers by place value? (I dont mean a `list()`, but just some numbers)

For e.g.:

I have a some numbers 1, 2, 3, and i am looking for a function which converts it to 123 (one hundred and twenty-three).

I thought I found a solution for this with  `read-string`

```
(read-string (str 1 2 3))
;=> 123
```

but sadly it not works well if i want to use it in the function discussed below.

I have a "functionmade" map where keys are vectors and values are numbers. Like this:
{[0 0] 0, [0 1] 1, ... [4 5] 45, ... [9 9] 99}

The only way i can use `get` function on this map is:

```
(get {[0 2] 2} [0 2])
;=> 2
; or
(get {[4 5] 45} [4 5])
;=> 45
```

This is grinding, but it works. To make it look much better i tried to define a function where i used `read-string`: (read/ refers to cljs.reader)

```
(defn get-oxo [x y]
  (get {[x y] (read/read-string (str x y))} [x y]))
;So i can use it like this for e.g.:
(get-oxo 4 5)
;=> 45
```

It also returns values which are not in the map:

```
(get-oxo 112 358)
;=> 112358
```

I suppose the problem is that this way `get-oxo` returns not the value of the paired key, but the number constructed from x y...

So the questions is how can I fix it to return the value of the paired key and not the number constructed from the numbers i give to the functions?

(There is another problem if i want to generate a map with wider range of numbers, for e.g. not just 0-9 but 0-99. This way the algorythm of `get-oxo` is not true. I use the function discussed at: [ClojureScript zipmap tricks me or what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48652038/clojurescript-zipmap-tricks-me-or-what)).

Comment: how do you suppose to get in item from the map, if the map is not being the argument of `get` function? i mean you are getting the value you generate. That's it. Seems like you have the fundamental misunderstanding of the programming at all, not just **clojure** programming.

Comment: What's the point in using a map if you're only interested in its keys and never its values?

Comment: @TaylorWood I will define values later, not clear yet.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is you get what you put:

just decompose your function to see it clearly:

```
(defn get-oxo [x y]
  (let [new-map {[x y] (read/read-string (str x y))}]
    (println new-map)
    (get new-map [x y])))
#'user/get-oxo

user> (get-oxo 100 200)
;;=> {[100 200] 100200}
;;=> 100200
```

So you generate your map inside the function, and get it's key
and you get... a totally valid behavior

to get something from **your** map , you need to have **your** map as the first argument of `get` function

```
(defn get-oxo [input x y]
  (get input [x y]))
#'user/get-oxo

user> (def data {[0 0] 0 [0 1] 1 [0 2] 2})
#'user/data

user> (get-oxo data 0 1)
1

user> (get-oxo data 2 3)
nil
```

then, if you need the key (i mean pair from map) instead of value, you can modify it this way, using `find` function instead of `get`:

```
(defn get-oxo [input x y]
  (first (find input [x y])))
#'user/get-oxo

user> (get-oxo data 0 1)
[0 1]

user> (get-oxo data 2 3)
nil
```

also writing and reading string to get a number looks redundant. You can easily make a simple function for that:

```
(defn digits->num [digits]
  (reduce (fn [acc d] (+ (* 10 acc) d))
          0
          digits))
#'user/digits->num

user> (digits->num [0])
0

user> (digits->num [])
0

user> (digits->num [1])
1

user> (digits->num [1 2 3 4])
1234

user> (digits->num [0 0 1 0])
10
```

Comment: OK, i realised 2 things now.

Comment: OK, i realised 2 things now.
1. I was totally stupid when i defined `get-oxo`. No more words on this...
2. I was not clear enough. The problem with your solution is that it works on a map but actually my map is function... I mean i used a function to generate a map, so i cant treat it as data. (To generate the map this way is important). Is there a way in this case to refer on the generated map? Other suggestion?

Comment: Anyway thanks for your answer this helped me a lot and i have also learned a new thing: `find`.

Comment: it would be nice, if you could update your answer with 1) the signature of your map generating function, 2) the signature of the function you need to make up (getter) and the example how you want to use it. Your above comment made it even more obscure: You have function, producing a collection, you want to get the value from that collection. So you call this function and get the key from its output (which is a map). Where am i wrong?

Comment: You are totally rigth. If i will have more time i define a new and much more understandable  question and i invite you there.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply [`apply`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/apply) [`str`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/str) function to your sequence of digits:

```
(apply str '(1 2 3))
;; => "123"
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i did. The problem comes in the next step if you have read the whole question. (I know it is long to read, sorry).

Comment: Oh or maybe i was not clear enough. I edit the post.